# MediaWiki panic after modifying a file. Checksums maybe?

Tags: mediawiki, checksum

I've recently installed the latest version of MediaWiki on a dev server. I wanted to add some information on the edit page, and for this needed to modify an existing .php file to add in some more text.

I used grep to find which file contained the text I wanted to change. It turned out to be languages/messages/MessagesEn.php. I found the text and changed it to what I wanted it to be.

I only ended up adding a couple lines of extra information that lies right below the copyright notice on "edit" pages. Now I can't get to the homepage of my wiki.

Does anyone know why this is? MediaWiki is open source so changing the source code shouldn't be a big deal. I thought maybe there was some kind of checksum check and seeing as I modified the file, MediaWiki panicked when it saw the file didn't have the same checksum.

Ideas?

**edit:** I removed the text I added to the file and MediaWiki is back in business. This shows that the text I added was/is the issue. I still want that text there, so my question is still valid.

**update:**

Here is the bit I'm editing:

```
'copyrightwarning'                 => "Please note that all contributions to {{SITENAME}} are considered to be released under the $2 (see $1 for details).
If you do not want your writing to be edited mercilessly and redistributed at will, then do not submit it here.<br />
You are also promising us that you wrote this yourself, or copied it from a public domain or similar free resource.
'''Do not submit copyrighted work without permission!'''",
'copyrightwarning2'                => "Please note that all contributions to {{SITENAME}} may be edited, altered, or removed by other contributors.
If you do not want your writing to be edited mercilessly, then do not submit it here.<br />
You are also promising us that you wrote this yourself, or copied it from a public domain or similar free resource (see $1 for details).
'''Do not submit copyrighted work without permission!'''",
```

I'm changing the text to something like this:

```
'copyrightwarning'                 => "Please note that all contributions to {{SITENAME}} are considered to be released under the $2 (see $1 for details).
If you do not want your writing to be edited mercilessly and redistributed at will, then do not submit it here.<br />
You are also promising us that you wrote this yourself, or copied it from a public domain or similar free resource.
'''Do not submit copyrighted work without permission!''' **blah blah blah blah**",
'copyrightwarning2'                => "Please note that all contributions to {{SITENAME}} may be edited, altered, or removed by other contributors.
If you do not want your writing to be edited mercilessly, then do not submit it here.<br />
You are also promising us that you wrote this yourself, or copied it from a public domain or similar free resource (see $1 for details).
'''Do not submit copyrighted work without permission!''' **blah blah blah blah**",
```

Is there a reason MediaWiki is panicking here? I'll try to provide as much information as possible on this, but I'm not at the office again until Monday. Thanks

Comment: This isn't an answer as it isn't solved. I've only confirmed the issue was with the text editing. I still want it there.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't screw up any PHP syntax?

Comment: What do you see when try to access the homepage of your wiki? A blank page?

Comment: Looks like you want to check where thouse php error messages go on your server.

Comment: Post the section of `MessagesEn.php` you are trying to modify. Both the original and the modified version. It is more than likely just an invalid format issue, either PHP or MediaWiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your edit broke some PHP, probably because of improper escaping of characters.

Most things in MediaWiki do not involve direct edits to `.php` files.  Edits to system messages happen within the MediaWiki interface, as would edits for any other page.  System messages are located at the following Special page:

http://example.com/index.php?title=Special:AllMessages

Specifically, for your copyright messages:

http://example.com/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Copyrightwarning&action=edit

http://example.com/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Copyrightwarning2&action=edit